# How do I insert an image in a word document as footer

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I need to create and insert a QR code into existing word documents using .NET.
I've done the QR generation part. The 2 things I need to accomplish are:

1. Inserting the QR code in the footer of an existing word document (preferably using Open XML).
2. Each page of the word document has a unique QR code. This means that each footer would have to be different. (I could eliminate the footer and place the QR code as part of the body, but that word make flow of text complicated.)

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but I *believe* that what you will need to do is

1. put each page in a separate Word section (and that means, in effect,
   that you will need to decide what your page size and layout is)
2. create a footer containing one QR code to find out what XML Word
   expects, and what type of image data you need to store in the .docx
   (assuming that you are not attempting to store your image data
   externally in spearate files).
3. create a footer for each section (and ensure that the footers are
   not "linked to previous"), replicating the format you discovered in
   point (2)
4. create a part for each QR code image, and a relationship to that
   part

What I am even less sure about is whether Word will insist that you also store each image in another format (e.g. Windows Metafile or Extended metafile format). My guess is that Word will generate what it needs from your .jpg (or whatever). Or maybe you can use "AltChunks" in some useful way here.

The background to this is that if it were a .doc format document, you could have created a single footer containing a set of nested field codes that used the { PAGE } page number field to link to the correct image for each page - e.g.

```
{ INCLUDETEXT "c:\\myqrcodes\\qr{ PAGE }.jpg" }
```

or more likely, the slightly more complicated

```
{ PAGE \#"'{ INCLUDETEXT "c:\\myqrcodes\\qr{ PAGE }.jpg" }'" }
```

But if you try to save that as .docx format, even in compatibility mode, when you close and re-open, I think you wil just see one image on all pages. Further, even though that approach works with .doc format, it only works if the external image files are actually there and located at absolute addresses in the file system. If they are located at releative addresses (there is a way to do that) you or the end user will probably have to update the footer field codes to get the correct results.